# Output of a shell script is another shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which will print another shell script to stdout. I need to execute both the scripts (initial script and output script) with a single line bash command. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate, what exactly you mean by `which will print another shell script to stdout`

Comment: @Incognito: which part of this is not clear?

Comment: Example, 1.sh = `echo "ls"`. so i have two execute 1.sh which will print/generate a new script and i have to run that script. In the example final output should be the output of ls . (1.sh can generate multiline scripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
sh ./test.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
bash test.bash | bash -s
```